# Offset points to show multiple points in one location, while simultaneously showing two categories of points

Tags: arcmap, symbology, overlapping-features, offset

**Problem:**
I'm using ArcMap 10.7.1. I have a dataset that has two categories (A and B) of points and has multiple points in one location. I want to "jitter" or offset these points from each other, so every point can be seen on the map, but also show two different categories. I have over 100 points.

**Example of data:**

```
Lat, Lon, Category
55.18, 14.80, A
55.18, 14.80, A
55.18, 14.80, B
56.53, 16.55, A
56.53, 16.55, A
54.42, 11.24, A
54.42, 11.24, B
56.96, 18.26, A
```

**What I've tried:**

1. I tried to symbolize by categories (A and B) and graduated symbols.
       I couldn't figure out how to use both at once, however, since some
       of my points only differ by 0.01, this method wouldn't work anyway,
       as some points would still overlap depending on scale.
2. I also tried manually jittering them, but with so many data points,
       this would take an unreasonable amount of time.

Is there an easier way to jitter or offset points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requires an Advanced license, but is [Disperse Markers](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/tools/cartography-toolbox/disperse-markers.htm) what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have an advanced license, but I'm now using someone else's in order to use disperse markers. For future reference, is there any other way to disperse without an advanced licence?